# Find distance to vertex of equilateral triangle enclosing circle

Tags: geometry, triangles

If I have a circle with radius $r$, how do I find the distance to a vertex of the minimal equilateral triangle that encloses it? [Image source](https://geometryhelp.net/area-of-circle-inscribed-in-equilateral-triangle/)

[image]

Comment: What is angle $EBO$? What is angle $EOB$? What kind of triangle is $\triangle EOB$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Shouldn't it be 30 degrees?

Comment: Yes: it’s a 30-60-90 right triangle, and we know one side, so we’re home free.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Got it thanks! :)

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Since EBD is $60^0$, and by property of circle EB=BD, thus triangle EBO is an equilateral triangle.

Also EOD is an isosceles triangle & EOD is $120^0$. So, EOB is $60^0$. Thus $b=r\cos 60=\frac{r}{2}$.

Finding the length of BF now,
We know that $a=r\sin 60=\frac{r\sqrt3}{2}$. ED=$r\sqrt3$.
ED=EB=BD.

So, BF=EB$\sin 60=\frac{3r}{2}$.

**Hence, OB=OF(i.e. b)+BF=$\frac{r}{2}+\frac{3r}{2}=2r$**

Thus, the distance from the vertex to the circle is...

> 2r-r=**r**

Answer (score 1):

You can clearly see that the angle $EOD$ is $120$ degrees because it is carving out a third of the circle. This is due to the symmetry of an equilateral triangle. Knowing this, because the segment $BO$ bisects the angle $EOD$, we have that $EOB$ is a $60$ degree angle and therefore the triangle $EOB$ is a $30-60-90$ triangle. That makes the length of the segment $BO$ equal to $2r$ and consequently the distance from the circle to the vertex $2r-r =r$ because we subtract out the radius of the circle.

Comment: I tested this by drawing it out, and $r√3$ distance doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: You are right I made a mistake and now I’ve updated my answer.

Comment: That's a sweet relationship, thanks!